# Need help in layout two graphs in one page using grid arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, layout

I have two plots I want to display them on one page with common legend, I have tried all possibilities but none of them work.
Below are the code and the desired results:

```
library(ggplot2)
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library("rnaturalearth")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
# first plot
grd1<- data.frame(lon=rep(seq(12,18,0.25),13), lat=rep(seq(33.5, 36.5, 0.25),25),a= runif(325))
p1<- ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill="antiquewhite") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(12, 18), ylim = c(30, 40), expand = FALSE)+
  geom_raster(data=grd1, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = a ),interpolate = FALSE) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

# second plot
grd2<- data.frame(lon=rep(seq(12,18,0.25),13), lat=rep(seq(33.5, 36.5, 0.25),25),a= runif(325))
p2<- ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill="antiquewhite") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(12, 18), ylim = c(30, 40), expand = FALSE)+
  geom_raster(data=grd2, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = a ),interpolate = FALSE) 


# Get the legend
library(gridExtra)
get_legend<-function(myggplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(myggplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)
}
legend<- get_legend(p1)
p1<-p1+ theme(legend.position="none")
p2<-p2+ theme(legend.position="none")

# layout the two plots in one page
grid.arrange(
  grobs=list(p1, p2, legend), ncol=2,nrow=2,
  layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,2),c(3,3)),
  widths=c(4,4)
)
```

This code yields the following result
[image]

The desired result should look like this
[image]

Comment: Maybe `heights=c(4,2)` after `widths=c(4,4)` is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to achieve this would be to make use of `patchwork` which via `plot_layout` makes it possible to collect the guides. To make this work we have to set the same limits for the fill scale so that the fill legends are the same (otherwise the scale of your fill legends will be slightly different):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(rnaturalearth)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
# first plot
grd1<- data.frame(lon=rep(seq(12,18,0.25),13), lat=rep(seq(33.5, 36.5, 0.25),25), a= runif(325))
p1<- ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill="antiquewhite") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(12, 18), ylim = c(30, 40), expand = FALSE)+
  geom_raster(data=grd1, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = a ),interpolate = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))
# second plot
grd2<- data.frame(lon=rep(seq(12,18,0.25),13), lat=rep(seq(33.5, 36.5, 0.25),25), a= runif(325))
p2<- ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(fill="antiquewhite") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(12, 18), ylim = c(30, 40), expand = FALSE)+
  geom_raster(data=grd2, aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = a ),interpolate = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) 

p1 + p2 + 
  plot_layout(guides = "collect") & 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: Your attempt makes the plots look better.  But what about making them look square rather than rectangular?  how can I do that?

Comment: Hm. You could use `theme(legend.position = "bottom", aspect.ratio = 1)`. However, as you are plotting a map you have to keep in mind that doing so "distorts" the map, i.e. you stretch the map. For that reason maps are by default plotted using fixed coords which is the reason for the rectangular look.